# Importing Google contacts to kaddressbook?

Tags: contacts, kaddressbook

I can't seem to figure out just how to import Google contacts to my kadressbook.

Do I have to email myself the .csv file or do I put it on a flash, or what?

Answer (score 1):

To transfer your contacts over simply do the following:

Go to your gmail account and export you contact list as .csv. After this, simply go to your e-mail program and select File > Import. Contacts should be somewhere in this list.

Note: I may not have all of the specific detail correct. If someone else sees that I have misinformed in this post, please edit it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide here:
https://userbase.kde.org/Working_with_Google_Contacts

The package to install used to be called `akonadi-kde-resource-googledata`.

Unfortunately it did not work for me, as the akonadi-resource crashed while trying to configure it.

**In Ubuntu 21.10** the package doesn't exist anymore, but you can do this:

Open Kaddressbook Menu and go to **File > New > Add Address Book**.

In the dialog Google should be selectable.